# EditText Numbers Only using C#?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext, int

I'm calling an EditText within a AlertDialogue and I want it to only accept numbers/have the number keyboard.
There's no XML of the EditText to android:input="numbers" it.

```
...
EditText en = new EditText(this);
Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder at = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
at.SetTitle("Unit Initiative");
at.SetMessage("Please enter a number");
at.SetView(en);

at.SetPositiveButton("Add", delegate
{
    int number;
    bool success = Int32.TryParse(en.Text, out number);
    if (success)
    {
        itemUnit.ItemNumber = number;
        ItemUnits.Add(itemUnit);
        iuAdapter.Add(itemUnit);
        iuAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else
    {
        en.Text = "";
        Toast.MakeText(this, 
                       "Please Input a Number", 
                        ToastLength.Short).Show();

    }
});
at.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", delegate
{
    return;
});
at.Show();
});
ad.SetCancelable(true);

ad.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", delegate
{
    return;
});
ad.Show();
};
}
```

The current method isn't great and will make the popup fail to add the item to the list if you don't enter a number.

I'd rather just have a way to set it to have a number keyboard only but the only solutions I see are through XML or Java, is there a C# alternative to force the Edittext keyboard to be numbers only?

Comment: the code appears to have more closing brackets than the opening ones

Comment: It probably does. This is just a snippet so it's inside something else. This problem has been solved though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `InputType` property of your EditText and set it to `InputTypes.ClassNumber` in order to only show a keyboard with numbers.

Ex. : `editText.InputType = InputTypes.ClassNumber;`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @Mada, it seems that Rushguy23's reply help you, please remember to mark this reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.